# How to hide video player of HTML5 play button in android WebView

Tags: java, css, html

I have faced a problem in Android Studio with a HTML5 video player.

I have to hide the default video play button in CSS but it's showing in Android Studio WebView below is my code.

```
#video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button
{
    display: none;
}
```

It's hidden in the desktop browser but not hidden in Android Studio WebView.

Comment: Please help me anyone